# Get dynamic value from jsp to servlet class

Tags: servlets

In my jsp, i have checkbox in while loop, so the name of the checkbox is dynamic, it depends on the while loop. There is a "Process" button, when i click on that button, it will send this checkbox parameter to a servlet class.

```
<TD width="10%"><input type="checkbox" name="chkTableType<%=i%>"  ></TD>
```

In my servlet, it will retrieve the value from jsp, i can do something like:

```
String date = request.getParameter("??");
```

The ?? is the name of the html checkbox, but since my checkbox name is dynamic, how to i get the value? If database has 10 values, i have 10 checkboxes.

Answer (score 0):

Let's assume that your jsp names the checkboxes "mycheckbox0", "mycheckbox1", ...

In your servlet, call request.getParameterNames(). Roll through all the names in a loop and look for the ones that start with "mycheckbox". Then, for each name, call request.getParameter(name) and get the value.

Keep in mind that checkboxes are a bit odd in that they will send a value if checked, but nothing if unchecked. You'll need to account for that in your code.